# How to call a void method from using android ndk

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to call a void method from my C++ code. I already have *jclass*, and JNIEnv*. I have no problem calling static methods, because I can simply use the *jclass* instance that I have. However, Using *env->CallVoidMethod()*, I read that I need to pass an object instead. The method is a part of my MainActivity class, so do I need to create an instance of the MainActivity class as seen in the debugging screenshot attached below? If so, how do I get the constructor Method ID for MainActivity?

[image: Debugging]

-------------UPDATE code shown below-------------

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass((MenuUtilities::getPathFromPackage() + "/MainActivity").c_str());
jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "MainActivity", "()V"); //This returns null..
jobject newObj = env->NewObject(clazz, constructor);
```

Comment: yes, to call a non-static method you need an object to call it on

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why am I getting null returned for My Method ID in the MainActivity Constructor? @AlanBirtles

Comment: not without a [mre]. You might also want to read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656)

Comment:  my screenshot is my code that I'm working with. but I'll still edit my post to show more.

Comment: The constructor is `<init>` not the class name